# Website design - 360 tour - fitting the with of the window

Tags: php, html, photo

I was wondering how to make the 360 virtual tour linked in this code fit the width of the window of which the tour is being viewed. As you can see now, the width is static at '1600' I know nothing about coding. I copy and pasted this from the code someone else did for me. If possible I would appreciate something I could paste back into the php file(*haha nervous laugh*).

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
<head>


<title>Footage Marketing | 360 Virtual Real Estate Tours</title>

<!-- Meta Tags Subroutine -->
<?php include("meta_sub.php"); ?>

<!-- End Head and Start Body -->
</head>
<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 link="grey" vlink="grey">

<!-- Style Sheets -->
<?php include("style.php"); ?>

<!-- Link to virtual tour-->


<script async src="https://static.theasys.io/embed.js" data-theasys="L3qvbCHtbsfLwgMoUVGvwYmU7juxCX" 
data-width="1600" data-height="800">
</script>


           
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only change data-width and data-height to 100%
If you get scroll in your page, you can change those to 99%